# Error al obtener edad por fecha de nacimiento - SQL SERVER

Tags: sql, sql-server

En estos momentos estoy que muestro datos de una persona como son sus datos personales y su edad pero su edad lo muestro en años, meses y dias calculandolo por su fecha de nacimiento y la fecha actual. Tengo un problema y es que algunas edades de algunas personas salen en negativo en sus dias y ademas de eso no da el valor exacto...Aqui un ejemplo:

- Persona X
- FechaNacimiento: 2018-07-26 00:00:00.000
- FechaActual: 2019-04-25
- Edad: deberia salir 0 años 8 meses 29 dias aproximadamente

Pero bueno, no me sale asi. Me sale como Edad: 1 años 9 meses -1 dia

Este error lo tengo en algunos datos. Mi codigo:

```
SELECT top 10
DatosNA as Nombres,
CONVERT(varchar(5), DATEDIFF(YEAR,FechaNacimiento,getdate()))+' Anios '+
CONVERT(varchar(5), DATEDIFF(MONTH,FechaNacimiento,getdate())%12)+' Meses '+
CONVERT(varchar(5), DATEPART(DAY, getdate()) - DATEPART(DAY, FechaNacimiento))+' Dias' as Edad,
FechaNacimiento
FROM Personas
```

Esta mal mi codigo? O que esta mal?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Para obtener la edad en años, meses y días, debes tener en cuenta si la fecha y día actual, sin tomar en cuenta el año, es mayor o menor que la fecha de nacimiento, y en base a eso, sumar o restar años y meses a la pura diferencia que resulta entre las fechas.

Es más fácil explicarlo en código, lo que hago es un CTE dónde:

- `Personas` lo construyo para simular tu tabla de personas
- en `Calculo`, determino el año, mes y día de la fecha de nacimiento y de hoy, además del cálculo de los días que tenía el mes de nacimiento de la persona, a manera de dar un cálculo correcto de días (con lo cual, tu fecha propuesta da un resultado de 0 años, 8 meses y 30 días, no 29).
- Finalmente, en el *query*, utilizo esta información para comparar las fechas con la lógica que me devuelva el valor correcto de la edad calculada en años, meses y días:

El resultado final es este:

```
with
Personas as (
          select 'Juan' DatosNA, cast('20180726' as date) FechaNacimiento
union all select 'Pedro' DatosNA, cast('20180101' as date) FechaNacimiento
union all select 'Matías' DatosNA, cast('20181224' as date) FechaNacimiento
union all select 'Damian' DatosNA, cast('20181225' as date) FechaNacimiento
union all select 'Elena' DatosNA, cast('20181226' as date) FechaNacimiento
union all select 'María' DatosNA, cast('20180424' as date) FechaNacimiento
union all select 'José' DatosNA, cast('20180425' as date) FechaNacimiento
union all select 'Inés' DatosNA, cast('20180426' as date) FechaNacimiento
union all select 'Francisco' DatosNA, cast('20180426' as date) FechaNacimiento
union all select 'Lucía' DatosNA, cast('20180220' as date) FechaNacimiento
union all select 'Renata' DatosNA, cast('20180224' as date) FechaNacimiento
union all select 'Amarilis' DatosNA, cast('20180225' as date) FechaNacimiento
union all select 'Isabel' DatosNA, cast('20180226' as date) FechaNacimiento
union all select 'Antonio' DatosNA, cast('20180227' as date) FechaNacimiento
union all select 'Mario' DatosNA, cast('20000227' as date) FechaNacimiento
union all select 'Flor' DatosNA, cast('19000227' as date) FechaNacimiento
)
,
Calculo as (
SELECT   DatosNA as Nombres
       , FechaNacimiento
       , CAST(getdate() as date) FechaHoy
       , YEAR(FechaNacimiento) AnioNacimiento
       , MONTH(FechaNacimiento) MesNacimiento
       , DAY(FechaNacimiento) DiaNacimiento
       , YEAR(GETDATE()) AnioHoy
       , MONTH(getdate()) MesHoy
       , DAY(GETDATE()) DiaHoy
       , DAY(EOMONTH(FechaNacimiento)) DiasMesNacimiento
FROM Personas
)
select   a.Nombres
       , a.FechaNacimiento
       , a.FechaHoy
       , a.AnioHoy - a.AnioNacimiento - case when MesNacimiento * 100 + DiaNacimiento > MesHoy * 100 + DiaHoy then 1 else 0 end EdadAnio
       , a.MesHoy - a.MesNacimiento + case
                                        when DiaNacimiento > DiaHoy then case when MesNacimiento >= MesHoy then 11 else -1 end
                                        else case when MesNacimiento <= MesHoy then 0 else 12 end
                                      end EdadMes
       , a.DiaHoy - a.DiaNacimiento + case when DiaNacimiento > DiaHoy then DiasMesNacimiento else 0 end EdadDia
 from Calculo a;
```

Que me devuelve el siguiente resultado:

```
Nombres   FechaNacimiento FechaHoy   EdadAnio    EdadMes     EdadDia
--------- --------------- ---------- ----------- ----------- -----------
Juan      2018-07-26      2019-04-25 0           8           30
Pedro     2018-01-01      2019-04-25 1           3           24
Matías    2018-12-24      2019-04-25 0           4           1
Damian    2018-12-25      2019-04-25 0           4           0
Elena     2018-12-26      2019-04-25 0           3           30
María     2018-04-24      2019-04-25 1           0           1
José      2018-04-25      2019-04-25 1           0           0
Inés      2018-04-26      2019-04-25 0           11          29
Francisco 2018-04-26      2019-04-25 0           11          29
Lucía     2018-02-20      2019-04-25 1           2           5
Renata    2018-02-24      2019-04-25 1           2           1
Amarilis  2018-02-25      2019-04-25 1           2           0
Isabel    2018-02-26      2019-04-25 1           1           27
Antonio   2018-02-27      2019-04-25 1           1           26
Mario     2000-02-27      2019-04-25 19          1           27
Flor      1900-02-27      2019-04-25 119         1           26

(16 rows affected)
```

## Edición

He editado mi respuesta para realizar los siguientes cambios:

- Añadir más personas para probar algunos *corner cases* que me vinieron a la mente y con los que me di cuenta que había un error en el cálculo de los meses.
- Aplicar la sugerencia de Luis para simplificar el cálculo de los días del mes de nacimiento, con lo cual la solución queda mucho más elegante.

## Edición 2

Ahora he simplificado un poco la lógica del cálculo de la edad en meses, dando siempre el resultado correcto.

Comment: Gracias compañero! Pense que solo eran unas lineas mas para poder obtener las edades en esa forma pero no tome en cuenta los demas caracteristicas que hay al momento de poner una fecha. Aun asi gracias por la ayuda, me sirvio bastante mas la explicacion! (y)

Comment: Puedes reducir el cálculo de los días del mes de nacimiento mediante 2 funciones. `DAY(EOMONTH(FechaNacimiento))`

Comment: @Luis, tienes toda la razón, editaré mi respuesta, pues es mucho más limpio. Gracias!

Comment: @Jrse, he editado mi respuesta, pues había también un error en el cálculo de los meses. Ahora está funcionando bien. También he incluido la sugerencia de Luis para el cálculo de los días del mes de nacimiento.

Comment: @jachguate igualmente gracias, no se mucho sobre esos metodos por eso no me di cuenta de esos puntos. Gracias por editarlo!

Comment: @Luis gracias por apoyarme en esta pregunta. Te lo agradezco bastante! (y)

Comment: El que realmente ayudó fue jachguate, yo solo aporté un método corto. Los cálculos de edad son complicados por todas las variantes que tienen las fechas.

Comment: He hecho una segunda edición para dejar más concisa la lógica del cálculo de los meses de la edad. La idea del sitio es lograr la colaboración que se da, para mejorar las preguntas y respuestas, y así construir entre todos una importante base de conocimiento en español.

Answer (score 0):

en dias varia por uno, pero si se le agrega un mas uno sale ok igual a lo calculado con la funcion si fecha de excel.

en esta parte de la formula por dias

, a.DiaHoy - a.DiaNacimiento **+1** + case when DiaNacimiento > DiaHoy then DiasMesNacimiento else 0 end EdadDia